# How does the statement for creating classes work in Python?

Tags: python, class

When I create a ***class Test*** defining one method  "a", a object ***Test***, whose type is ***type*** ,is created. The ***dir*** function give-us the names of the attributes/methods of an object. But when I code:

```
class Test():
   def a:
     pass
print(dir(Test))
```

I get:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', 'a']
```

from where did this "a" come from?

I thought "a" would be a method from a object whose class is Test, but the ***Test*** object itself have the same method, How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought "a" would be a method from a object whose class is Test, but the Test object itself have the same method, How?

Classes are objects.  They can and do have attributes, including callable ones, just like any other object.  They obtain their initial complement of these from the execution of their `class` block.  In particular, class objects get a callable attribute for each function `def`ined in their `class` block.  That's just how it works.

Classes' callable attributes can be called directly, and sometimes they are intended to be used that way.  Those intended to be called directly are commonly called "class methods".

The magic, to the extent that there is any, is in invoking methods on instances: when `instance` is an instance of class `Klass`, and `instance` does not have its own attribute `method`, but `Klass` has a callable attribute by that name, then Python interprets `instance.method()` as `Klass.method(instance)`.  That can be done explicitly, too, as if `method` were a class method -- in that sense, Python does not make a strong distinction between class and instance methods.

Answer (score 0):

The method is an attribute of the class. You can see that with `getattr`:

```
>>> getattr(Test, "a")
<function Test.a at 0x0000026826FCA9D0>
```

or if you use the modified, slightly bizarre-looking calling syntax:

```
t = Test()  # An instance
Test.a(t)
```

Here, `t` is being manually supplied as `self`.

From my understanding (I've been meaning to look into it further), these are equivalent:

```
t.a()
Test.a(t)
```